# Windows Store experiments clarification

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

Have couple questions about how works Windows Store experiments:

1. Preinstalled apps. No signing with ms account. No internet connection.

   Which data expected in this case for user? The local default data(see example) or default data that point at store's experiment at the release moment?

   *ex: value = _variation.GetString("buttonBackgroundColor", "#FFA3A3A3")*
2. How Store's experiment identity the app? by device? by ms account? Or how app take part at statistics?

Answer (score 0):

> Which data expected in this case for user? The local default data(see example) or default data that point at store's experiment at the release moment?

I think no data will be collected if a user uses the app without internet connection. And you can post this question at the bottom of [**this page**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/create-and-run-your-first-experiment-with-a-b-testing).

> How Store's experiment identity the app? by device? by ms account? Or how app take part at statistics?

Each app in the store has it's identity for recognition, which is unique, and you can view the details from your Dev Center Dashboard: click **App Management**>**App identity**. Store detects an app by `Store ID`.

Comment: Thanks, for answers. Misunderstanding. First question about which data was received when app will make a call to receive experiments data(see example).

Second question about how experement identity the app (instance of app) to define which variation will send to it. F.e. Will app receive the same variation or it can be changed during experiment on the different devices with same ms-account? Actually, I received an answer: experiment doesn't link with ms-account, spesific device. So one ms-account able to see different experement's result at tablet and phone or pc.